# Play video online

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

How to play a video from an online link? Its like streaming video. I'm using MPMoviePlayerController kit. I replaced the movie URL with online link. The modal view controller of video came but went off suddenly. Why is this so? The URL used is http://www.eesnap.com//medias//609f34c870721d57c65356c79c5304fc.mov

Thanks Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this issue before. The problem lies in the servers metadata. If it responds with the wrong mime-type, or the wrong content-length then you'll get this behavior. Furthermore there's a little known concept called progressive download that is enforced on iOS and Mac. I haven't tried but you may get the video to play on other platforms (Eg. Windows/Linux/Android) but with iOS/OSX/Quicktime the client player is sending ContentRange HTTP headers to request portions of the file and the server has to respond intelligently. I've actually built progressive download support by hand into a Java servlet some time ago and it was a little tricky.

Comment: can u give me any links which state the above in detail Cliff. :) Thanks for the support

Comment: I can't remember exactly where I found the detail on progressive downloads for iOS I only recall it was an arduous exercise in patience and research when we were trying to implement Text To Speech in an iPhone web app. I ran up against your very same problem a few years back. I think finally broke down and inspected the HTTP conversation when I realized the Content-Range headers in the request. I think I still have some posts here from my servlet development.

Comment: Here's my old post from way back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782128/allow-progressive-download-from-a-servlet

Comment: No prob. Wish I had more time to elaborate. I should probably add something about it on my blog.

Answer (score 1):

Just `init` your media controller with the `NSUrl`:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asCwv6_YN7A&feature=g-vrec&context=G2e345b5RVAAAAAAAAAw"]];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

If it goes off suddenly, I suspect there's something wrong with the video rather than the code like it's an empty video(size-0) or something. I tried opening the link you've provided in a browser and it didn't play! It should be an issue with your server's video...

Answer (score 0):

i think it need to work properly. Can you please give more detail which url are you using is it from youtube or from server.

If youtube then you need to embedded URl and need to open it in uiwebview.

i think this may help to clear out your view.

Comment: its a server URL. The URL is http://www.eesnap.com//medias//609f34c870721d57c65356c79c5304fc.mov